# How to prove the changing of basis matrices is unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

Suppose A is matrix defined on C
I need to prove that A is written as  A=OTO*
T is triangular matrix
O* is Conjugate transpose

Is it enough (and how) if I proved that O is unitary that mean O* = (O inverse) and that just mean I proved A is traingularizable because its distinct polynomial is divided

Answer (score 1):

This is called the Schur decomposition. See [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition). For constructive proofs by induction, see the lecture notes [here](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2013_14/math108b_w2014/math108b_w2014_lecture5.pdf) or [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~kmill/math54sp16/mar31.pdf).

Comment: Ty, that was very helpful